# Locking a single NSPersistentDocument

Tags: cocoa, core-data, locking, document, persistent

My application currently uses CoreData as a backend to store to a single SQL data file stored in `~/Library/Application Support/MYAPP/MyDataFile.sqlite`. I know it's an unusual situation, but what is the best way to "lock" this file so that if the user decides (for whatever silly reason) to run a second copy of my app, Core Data won't freak out? Should I use something old school like writing a lockfile somewhere and checking for that, or is there a nicer more Cocoa way of doing this?

Comment: Is you app a command-line app? Unless it is, you probably don't have to worry. OS X doesn't usually allow multiple instances of a .app to be launched.

Comment: Yeah - you're right, it's probably being a bit overzealous. I've run two instances of the app, and I only get Core Data errors - it doesn't actually seem to write those changes/errors to the store.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to locking the SQLite file, you could try using [LSMultipleInstancesProhibited](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW1) to disallow your users running two application instances.

Edit: the downside is it will also prevent multiple users (fast user switching) from using your application concurrently, although they do not share the core data store.

Comment: Yeah, that's not quite what I need - I want users to be able to run my app in different accounts at the same time, just not at the same time. I think I will code something into the applicationWillFinishLaunching: method of my application delegate.