# Prevent multiple users from running application simultaneously on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, info.plist

The client application uses a shared (Core Data) store. This is located in the `/Users/Shared/` folder and has global read-write permissions.

I would like to prevent another user from logging in (fast user switching) and simultaneously running the application and editing the same store.

Checking `-[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:]` only lists instances running under the current user.

*Is there a simple way to force single application instances across all users?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **LSMultipleInstancesProhibited** to the Info.plist file.

```
<key>LSMultipleInstancesProhibited</key>
<true/>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1896997/3342547) and [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html).