# How to prevent macOS Catalina from opening multiple instances of the same application?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, app-bundle

I have a bundled Java app. After updating to Catalina (10.15) I'm able to open as many instances as i want of my app. I use `open -a MyAppName` in Terminal. On macOS prior to Catalina only one instance would open no matter how many times I execute the open command. In Catalina however, every command execution results in another instance of my app.

Can someone point me to a change in Catalina which causes this behaviour?

**Edit #1**

Try to answer some questions from comments:

My question is, if there's an official documentation pointing to a solution to have the behaviour prior to Catalina back?

The app is a self developed bundled app, which is signed with a Developer ID and notarized by Apple

Comment: _You_ have described the change. What’s the question?

Comment: Also where is the programming in this question?

Comment: Something has changed regarding this, I also noticed some problem with emacs (on the contrary if it is already launched, it cannot receive more "open file" request from the command line).

Comment: Okay something changed. That could be true. But what is the _question_ suitable for Stack Overflow? What answer would satisfy you?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657629/prevent-multiple-users-from-running-application-simultaneously-on-macos